# Guardar valores em Hashtable

Tags: c#, .net, string

Quando guardo o valor desta `Hastable` ele dá-me erro.

Segue o código:

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add("index", index);
ht.Add("tipo", "1");

string tipo = ht["tipo"];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando fazes o return de um valor de uma Hastable tens de o converter para String assim:

```
string tipo = ht["tipo"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro, não use esta estrutura de dados, ela é considerada obsoleta e não deveria mais ser usada por nenhuma aplicação. Prefira a [`Dictionary<K, V>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0). Feito isto o problema não ocorrerá. Se insistir terá problemas de performance e erros deste tipo, que até podem ser solucionados (fazendo conversão, por exemplo), mas não vale o esforço.

```
var ht = new Dictionary<string, string> { ["index"] = "0", ["tipo"] = "1" };
string tipo = ht["tipo"];
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LdoFuY). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TS3siR). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/Dictionary2.cs).

Comment: Obrigado, mas o exercício pedia imperativamente Hastable :)

Comment: Obrigado, mas o exercício pedia imperativamente Hastable :)

Comment: Pula fora do exercício. Coisa que pede pra fazer coisa errada só te trará prejuízos.